# Adding Special Characters to SpriteFont

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, spritefont

I am trying to add the arrow keys ►, ◄, ▲, ▼ to my spritefont. They are Alt16, Alt17, Alt30, Alt31.

Here is what I am trying to do.

```
<CharacterRegions>
  <CharacterRegion>
    <Start>&#16;</Start>
    <End>&#17;</End>
  </CharacterRegion>
  <CharacterRegion>
    <Start>&#30;</Start>
    <End>&#126;</End>
  </CharacterRegion>
</CharacterRegions>
```

I am getting an error at the **16** / **17** and **30**.

The errors are:

```
Error   6   Character ' ', hexadecimal value 0x3 is illegal in XML documents.  
Error   7   Character ' ', hexadecimal value 0x1e is illegal in XML documents.  
Error   4   Character ' ', hexadecimal value 0x12 is illegal in XML documents.  
Error   2   Character ' ', hexadecimal value 0x11 is illegal in XML documents.  
Error   5   Character ' ', hexadecimal value 0x11 is illegal in XML documents.  
Error   3   Character ' ', hexadecimal value 0x10 is illegal in XML documents.
```

Can anyone show me how to properly add them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the decimal value for your characters instead, check out [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25B2/index.htm) site which will show you all of the representations. (You can change the value in the URL to find different characters)

Your correct XML should be:

```
<CharacterRegions>
  <CharacterRegion>
    <Start>&#9650;</Start>
    <End>&#9668;</End>
  </CharacterRegion>
  <CharacterRegion>
    <Start>&#32;</Start>
    <End>&#126;</End>
  </CharacterRegion>
</CharacterRegions>
```